# text div with bookmark-like bar

Tags: css

I wrote [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/CMCM4/) for better explanation, so, how to make red bars fill the whole height of `.frame`? And may be there are any absolutely different better way to make things like this?

Comment: Rotation makes it more difficult, but perhaps this same-height approach can help: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: @SebastianG wow,cool article and nice blog:) I'll think about how to apply this for my issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it myself. [JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/scythargon/QPGfH/).

```
var move_bookmark = function(){
    var sh = parseInt($(this).css('height').replace('px',''));
    var ph = parseInt($(this).parent().css('height').replace('px',''));
    if (sh%2==0)//this is for solving [this problem] - 
//http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183018/pixel-rectangle-precise-rotating
    {
        if(ph%2!=0)
        {
            ph++;
            $(this).parent().css('height',ph+'px');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(ph%2==0)
        {
            ph++;
            $(this).parent().css('height',ph+'px');
        }
    }
    $(this).css('width',ph+'px');
    var sw = ph;
    var offset = parseInt(ph-sw/2-sh/2)+'px'
    console.log(sw+"/"+sh);
    $(this).css('top',offset);
    $(this).css('left',-sw/2+sh/2+'px');
    $(this).parent().css('padding','0px 0px 0px '+sh+'px');
}
$('.bookmark').each(move_bookmark);
```

Answer (score 1):

Positioned elements are no longer part of the layout, so they have no idea what the dimensions of the parent element are. You need to use JavaScript to do this.